# Binding web service (wsdl) error

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, eclipse-virgo

I'm running in Virgo (OSGi)

My binding.xml file:

```
<jaxws:bindings wsdlLocation="CustomerService.wsdl"
          xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
          xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
          xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <!-- <jaxws:enableAsyncMapping>true</jaxws:enableAsyncMapping> -->
  <jaxws:bindings  node="wsdl:definitions/wsdl:types/xs:schema">
      <jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                      parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDateTime"
                      printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDateTime"/>
        <jxb:javaType name="java.util.Date" xmlType="xs:date"
                      parseMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.parseDate"
                      printMethod="org.apache.cxf.xjc.runtime.DataTypeAdapter.printDate"/>
      </jxb:globalBindings>
  </jaxws:bindings>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Logs:

```
[2013-02-28 16:27:26.938] region-dm-12                 <AG0000E> Application context creation failure for bundle 'com.etasgroup.visu.graph.services' version '1.0.0.201302280924'. org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from URL [bundleentry://232.fwk1459808981/META-INF/spring/binding.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 57; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxws:bindings'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm.ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor$2.run(ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor.java:95)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxws:bindings'.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 21 common frames omitted

[2013-02-28 16:27:26.945] start-signalling-1           <DE0006E> Start failed for bundle 'com.etasgroup.visu.graph.services' version '1.0.0.201302280924'. org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from URL [bundleentry://232.fwk1459808981/META-INF/spring/binding.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 57; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxws:bindings'.
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:170)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.access$800(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:60)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$3.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.startRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.stageOne(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:224)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.refresh(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:177)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:157)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.blueprint.extender.internal.activator.LifecycleManager$1.run(LifecycleManager.java:211)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.agent.dm.ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor$2.run(ContextPropagatingTaskExecutor.java:95)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'jaxws:bindings'.
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
        ... 21 common frames omitted

[2013-02-28 16:27:26.961] start-signalling-1           <DE0010I> Stopping bundle 'com.etasgroup.visu.graph.services' version '1.0.0.201302280924'.
[2013-02-28 16:27:26.963] start-signalling-1           <DE0011I> Stopped bundle 'com.etasgroup.visu.graph.services' version '1.0.0.201302280924'.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try to declare the schema location ? (xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws/wsdl_customizationschema_2_0.xsd http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd")

Comment: Tried `xmlns:schemaLocation="java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws`, but not work